# Remove Filename dot (.)

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace

I'm looking for ways to remove the dot (.) Of the file below, but it seems to be recognized by the OS as an extension

*SEGA8031.2867*

I would like to modify it to the point that he would be like the file below. Replacing the dot "." by underline "_".

*SEGA8031_2867*

Did some testing with .bat but did not get the expected result.

```
REN *SEGA????.????* *SEGA????_????*
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "*sega8031.2867*"') do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!file!" "!file:SEGA8031.2867=SEGA8031_2867!"
  endlocal
)
```

Using my [JREN.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081):

```
jren "(SEGA8031)\.(2867)" "$1_$2"
```

Comment: Many thanks dbenham, your command line is working perfectly!                       I would like to implement it for her to take various other files with the same nomenclature, but changing the digit parts of the name, assuming SEGA0000.0000, SEGA1123.2321, SEGA5463.8791 for modifying SEGA0000_0000, SEGA1123_2321, SEGA5463_8791, I have several files as well. .. can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Batch has a string replacement syntax in variables.  It's `%variable:search=replace%`

```
> SET filename=SEGA8031.2867
> SET newfilename=%filename:.=_%
> echo %newfilename%
SEGA8031_2867
```

Comment: Many thanks Ryan for your answer, but I could not use the command line, I must add something else in it?